# Getting text between HTML <a> tag with beautifull soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape all movie names from a website.

```
url = 'https://www.boxofficemojo.com/year/world/2019/'
content = session.get(url, verify=False).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
movie = soup.find('a', {'class': 'a-link-normal'})
print(movie)
```

With this code I get the following result

```
<a class="a-link-normal" href="/?ref_=bo_nb_ydw_mojologo"></a>
```

However when I inspect the page I get the result below. The text between the 'a' tag is what I need.

```
<a class="a-link-normal" href="/releasegroup/gr3511898629/?ref_=bo_ydw_table_1">Avengers: Endgame</a>
```

How do I retrieve it?

Comment: what you get is the first link on the page - the logo in the top left corner of the page. I would suggest to search for `table` tag with `class="a-bordered a-horizontal-stripes a-size-base a-span12 mojo-body-table mojo-table-annotated scrolling-data-table"` and work from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
movie = soup.find('td', class_='a-text-left mojo-field-type-release_group')
print(movie.text)
```

Comment: I already tried something very similar to that.`movie = soup.find('td', {'class': 'a-text-left mojo-field-type-release_group'})` but it didn't work. Your way of writing it does the trick! Thx